# Unable to run visualvm in Ubuntu 22.x in WSL 2

Tags: java, wsl-2, ubuntu-22.04, visualvm, sdkman

I am on Windows 11. I have already setup Windows version of VisualVM and able to perfectly run it without any issues.
I wanted to try the Linux flavour. I setup sdkman, java, and maven. But for some reason I am unable to run visualvm successfully.

I think the issue is that `libXtst.so` is not available in Ubuntu 22. Ubuntu uses all lowercase letters or so I heard. But I am unable to troubleshoot further and fix the problem. I tried all Java 8, 17 and 21. I have even set flags manually: `visualvm --jdkhome=/home/ahroo/.sdkman/candidates/java/17.0.9-amzn`

I have added version details below.

```
ahroo@AhrooranR:/mnt/c/Users/AhrooranRavindran$ sdk default java
17.0.9-amzn   21.0.1-amzn   8.0.392-amzn
ahroo@AhrooranR:/mnt/c/Users/AhrooranRavindran$ java -version
openjdk version "21.0.1" 2023-10-17 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-21.0.1.12.1 (build 21.0.1+12-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-21.0.1.12.1 (build 21.0.1+12-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
ahroo@AhrooranR:/mnt/c/Users/AhrooranRavindran$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.9.4 (dfbb324ad4a7c8fb0bf182e6d91b0ae20e3d2dd9)
Maven home: /mnt/c/AHROO/programs/apache-maven-3.9.2
Java version: 21.0.1, vendor: Amazon.com Inc., runtime: /home/ahroo/.sdkman/candidates/java/21.0.1-amzn
Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-wsl2", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
ahroo@AhrooranR:/mnt/c/Users/AhrooranRavindran$ sdk default visualvm 2.1.7
setting visualvm 2.1.7 as the default version for all shells.
ahroo@AhrooranR:/mnt/c/Users/AhrooranRavindran$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
ahroo@AhrooranR:/mnt/c/Users/AhrooranRavindran$ visualvm
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/ahroo/.sdkman/candidates/java/21.0.1-amzn/lib/libawt_xawt.so: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:331)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:197)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:139)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2418)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:852)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:2021)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:331)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:197)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:139)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.findFromPaths(NativeLibraries.java:259)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:249)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2427)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:916)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:2059)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:67)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:319)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initStatic(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:64)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:59)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.PlatformGraphicsInfo.createGE(PlatformGraphicsInfo.java:37)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:93)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE.<clinit>(GraphicsEnvironment.java:84)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:106)
        at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Main.java:245)
        at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopThreadGroup.run(TopThreadGroup.java:98)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
```

I ran visual with console output. Perhaps this could help:

```
ahroo@AhrooranR:/mnt/c/Users/AhrooranRavindran$ visualvm -J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=true
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/ahroo/.sdkman/candidates/java/21.0.1-amzn/lib/libawt_xawt.so: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:331)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:197)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:139)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2418)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:852)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:2021)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:331)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:197)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:139)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.findFromPaths(NativeLibraries.java:259)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:249)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2427)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:916)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:2059)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:67)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:319)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initStatic(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:64)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:59)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.PlatformGraphicsInfo.createGE(PlatformGraphicsInfo.java:37)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:93)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE.<clinit>(GraphicsEnvironment.java:84)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:106)
        at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Main.java:245)
        at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopThreadGroup.run(TopThreadGroup.java:98)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>Log Session: Sunday, January 7, 2024, 6:02:00 PM India Standard Time
>System Info:
  Product Version         = VisualVM 2.1.7
  Operating System        = Linux version 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 running on amd64
  Java; VM; Vendor        = 21.0.1; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 21.0.1+12-LTS; Amazon.com Inc.
  Runtime                 = OpenJDK Runtime Environment 21.0.1+12-LTS
  Java Home               = /home/ahroo/.sdkman/candidates/java/21.0.1-amzn
  System Locale; Encoding = en (visualvm); UTF-8
  Home Directory          = /home/ahroo
  Current Directory       = /mnt/c/Users/AhrooranRavindran
  User Directory          = /home/ahroo/.visualvm/2.1.7
  Cache Directory         = /home/ahroo/.cache/visualvm/2.1.7
  Installation            = /home/ahroo/.sdkman/candidates/visualvm/current/visualvm
                            /home/ahroo/.sdkman/candidates/visualvm/current/platform
  Boot & Ext. Classpath   =
  Application Classpath   = /home/ahroo/.sdkman/candidates/visualvm/current/platform/lib/boot.jar:/home/ahroo/.sdkman/candidates/visualvm/current/platform/lib/org-openide-modules.jar:/home/ahroo/.sdkman/candidates/visualvm/current/platform/lib/org-openide-util-lookup.jar:/home/ahroo/.sdkman/candidates/visualvm/current/platform/lib/org-openide-util-ui.jar:/home/ahroo/.sdkman/candidates/visualvm/current/platform/lib/org-openide-util.jar
  Startup Classpath       = /home/ahroo/.sdkman/candidates/visualvm/current/platform/core/org-openide-filesystems.jar:/home/ahroo/.sdkman/candidates/visualvm/current/platform/core/core-base.jar:/home/ahroo/.sdkman/candidates/visualvm/current/platform/core/org-netbeans-libs-asm.jar:/home/ahroo/.sdkman/candidates/visualvm/current/platform/core/core.jar:/home/ahroo/.sdkman/candidates/visualvm/current/platform/core/asm-commons-9.2.jar:/home/ahroo/.sdkman/candidates/visualvm/current/platform/core/asm-tree-9.2.jar:/home/ahroo/.sdkman/candidates/visualvm/current/platform/core/asm-9.2.jar:/home/ahroo/.sdkman/candidates/visualvm/current/visualvm/core/org-graalvm-visualvm-modules-startup.jar:/home/ahroo/.sdkman/candidates/visualvm/current/visualvm/core/locale/core_visualvm.jar
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think the issue is that `libXtst.so` is not available in Ubuntu 22.

On a Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS system, following the suggestion in [How do I find the package that provides a file?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1912/1660836)  reports that that `libXtst.so` is provided by the `libxtst6:amd64` package:

```
$ apt-file find libXtst.so
libxtst-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXtst.so
libxtst6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6
libxtst6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6.1.0
```

Suggest try `sudo apt install libxtst6` to install the package, and see if:

1. That allows `visualvm` to run.
2. Or changes the error message to report a different missing dependant shared library. In which case the above example of using `apt-file find` to search for the package which provides a specific shared library, should allow you to locate and install the package which provides the shared library.